# How to download the encrypted attachment in corda?

Tags: corda

How to download the encrypted attachment in Corda? I have uploaded a file in corda and encrypted it and got the hash. How to download the same from other node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider, you have uploaded Jar as the attachment that contains a single file (e.g. legal agreement pdf), you can extract it as below:

```
//Get the attachmentJar from node for attachmentHash.
val attachmentJar: InputStream = cordaRPCOps.openAttachment(attachmentHash)

//Read the content of Jar to get file name and data.
var file_name_data: Pair<String, ByteArray>? = null
JarInputStream(attachment).use { jar ->
    while (true) {
        val nje = jar.nextEntry ?: break
        if (nje.isDirectory) {
            continue
        }
        file_name_data = Pair(nje.name, jar.readBytes())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If an attachment is referenced by hash in a transaction that node A sends to node B, and node B has never seen the attachment corresponding to that hash, they will automatically request the attachment from node A and cache it locally for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private fun downloadAttachment(proxy: CordaRPCOps, attachmentHash: SecureHash): JarInputStream {
        val attachmentDownloadInputStream = proxy.openAttachment(attachmentHash)
        return JarInputStream(attachmentDownloadInputStream)
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.